# unable to access element text from id

Tags: jquery, text

I'm trying to access the text of a span element using its id. Here's some  of the html (part of an English/Thai language site using click events to trigger audio files)

```
        <p class="link_box"><span class="color_up set1" id="s1e01">I can.. </span>ฉันสามารถ..</p>
        <p class="link_box"><span class="color_up set1" id="s1e02">I cannot (can’t)</span>ฉันไม่สามารถ..</p>
```

I want to use the span id  "s1e01" to access and display the text "I can..". Here is the js code:

```
var  word1 = "";     
  jQuery("div#word_set").click(function (evnt) {
    if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
      var elementId = evnt.target.id;
      word1 = jQuery(elementId).text();
      var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML;
      var oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg";
      var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      ...
```

the code "jQuery(elementId).text()" doesn't seem to be returning any value as word1 doesn't change from its initialized value of "". The problem seems to center around elementId, but I can't see what to use in its place. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to get the text from a specific SPAN, why are you using `evnt.target`? The target of the click event will always be the DIV with `id="word_set"`. What does this have to do with the `s1e01` SPAN?

Comment: Well, the div#word_set is used as delegation (I'm not sure if this is the right terminology) as there are a large number of spans with ids going from s1e01 to s1e50. Anyhow, the audio code works OK. The problem is accessing and displaying the text "I can..", "I cannot". etc. Basically, I want the user to hear and see the text.

Comment: Perhaps it should be something like `$("#word_set span").click()` or `$("#word_set span.set1")` to indicate that you're clicking on one of these sets. If they're added dynamically, you should use `.on()` to delegate.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I changed the set to `jQuery("div#word_set p span")` and `word1 = jQuery(this).text()`. Thanks for that. I would like to delegate but I'm not sure about using .on but I can check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use an element ID in a jQuery selector, you need the `#` prefix, so it should be:

```
word1 = jQuery('#'+elementId).text();
```

But why are you getting the ID in the first place? You already have a reference to the object, so you don't need to search for it. Just do:

```
word1 = jQuery(evnt.target).text();
```

Your handler could also be more refined:

```
jQuery("#word_set span.set1").click(function() {
    if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
        word1 = $(this).text();
        ...
```

When you bind the handler to the specific target, `this` is automatically set to the target. If these elements are added dynamically, you can use delegation:

```
jQuery("#word_set").on("click", "span.set1", function() {
    if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
        word1 = $(this).text();
        ...
```

Comment: That clarifies a lot. Thanks. I'm gradually getting my head around jQuery